# How to block any app from being installed apart from one app?

Tags: android, operating-system, android-source

I want to restrict the phone to install (Android 6) any app including all existing network apps (chrom, facebook etc) apart from one specific application.

I am thinking of editing the operating system, but I do not know which files to edit?

I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

The core part of app installation on AOSP is the `PackageManagerService`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-6.0.1_r81/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java

Follow the installation logic, and somewhere add a check for the specific applicantion's packageName that you want to allow, and just fail for all others

Comment: Hello, is this the only file that needs to be edited? Where can I find a guide to compiling the code?  Thanks

Comment: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building
Not that this link is for getting/building AOSP. If you want to build/flash a specific device, it's not that straighforward, as AOSP won't have the device specific code. You'd either get that from the vendor, or check  a ROM that supports your device.

Comment: It can be on different devices. I was thinking of using an old version (for example 6 ) to support them (without using a GPS, camera etc. - just a single app). Is the idea wrong?

Comment: The same build wont work on all devices. Each device has its custom things added by device vendor, and you cannot just flash a build from AOSP and expect it to work.
Your change in PackageManagerService will certainly be same, its just that HALs and other stuff will have to be device specific. You can either use a ROM with support for your device (e.g. https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/ ), or talk directly with the device vendor ( unlilkely to cooaperate with individual devs, just with partner companies )